# Discord Python add Nickname to a Player

Tags: python, discord

i coding with python for a discord bot
is there a way

`await member.edit(nick=":emoji:")`

that i edit a nickname from a player not completly?
i try `member.add (nick=":emoji:")` but did'nt work.
Is there a Way?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? What does your code do and what do you want it to do?

Comment: before this way, a member becomes a role with member_add_roles on raw reaction add.
`await member.add_roles(range, atomic=True)`
after this
should be a member become a emoji from the bot in his nickname in the front of his nickname

Comment: but i cant combine await member.edit(nick=None)
             #  await member.edit(nick="")

Comment: why do you want to combine those two

Comment: I want to combine this two because for a better overview in the Channel. 
At the moment we play New World and i or my member need a Better Overview to Look with what we play.
At beginning i add on_raw_reaction_add and all members can change his role. But now Member wishes that when they press the reaction that a bow for range or a mage in front of the nicknames come 
Sry for my English :)

Comment: so why do you need the `nick=None`?

Comment: i dont need this i need an :emoji: but i try to combine nick=None + nick = "emoji" because i want that the nickname still. I want not a Change from The Nickname i want to add the Emoji in Front of The Nickname, but the nickname have to stay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`None` won't help you.

To add the emoji to the start of someone's nickname:

```
await member.edit(nick = ":emoji:" + member.nick)
```

Comment: can i now combine the same with on_raw_reaction_remove when i remove the reaction that the emoji will removed?^^

Comment: `await member.remove_roles(Range, atomic=True)
                 await member.edit(nick=member.nick)`

Comment: `nick = member.nick.replace(":emoji:", "")`

Comment: I'm very grateful thank you :)